# Error in `ezANOVA` with balanced dataset with no missing data

Tags: r, experiment-design

This is cross-posted on StackExchange, but as it has to do with statistics, I thought I'd try here.

I'm trying to analyze experimental data with one between-subjects factor (`rank`) and two within-subjects factors (`cost`,`msg`) using the `ez` package. Participants were randomly assigned to both `cost` and `msg` at two points in time, so theoretically they could have the same combination of `cost` and `msg` at both points in time. `ezDesign` indicates that **my data is balanced with no missing values.**

Suppose my dataset `ez_data` looks like this:

```
     id choice_num choice        msg           cost   product            rank id_r
1.1   1    1      1 Provincial      Same cost   Cleaner Least important  1.1
2.1   2    1      1    No norm More expensive   Cleaner  Most important  2.1
3.1   3    1      1    No norm      Same cost      Soap Least important  3.1
4.1   4    1      1       Norm      Same cost    Coffee  Most important  4.1
5.1   5    1      1 Provincial      Same cost      Soap  Most important  5.1
6.1   6    1      1    No norm      Same cost Chocolate  Most important  6.1
7.1   7    1      1 Provincial      Same cost   Cleaner  Most important  7.1
8.1   8    1      0 Provincial      Same cost    Coffee Least important  8.1
9.1   9    1      1 Provincial      Same cost   Cleaner Least important  9.1
10.1 10    1      1       Norm More expensive Chocolate  Most important 10.1
11.1 11    1      1       Norm      Same cost      Soap  Most important 11.1
12.1 12    1      0 Provincial      Same cost    Coffee  Most important 12.1
13.1 13    1      1       Norm      Same cost      Soap  Most important 13.1
14.1 14    1      1 Provincial      Same cost      Soap Least important 14.1
15.1 15    1      0       Norm More expensive    Coffee  Most important 15.1
16.1 16    1      1 Provincial      Same cost   Cleaner Least important 16.1
17.1 17    1      1    No norm More expensive Chocolate Least important 17.1
18.1 18    1      0 Provincial More expensive      Soap Least important 18.1
19.1 19    1      1       Norm More expensive Chocolate  Most important 19.1
20.1 20    1      1 Provincial      Same cost   Cleaner Least important 20.1
```

Based on the comments [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ez4r/-2hjt8eiULc), I've created a new ID variable that concatenates the `choice_num` with the `id` variable so that there are no repeated values for the labels for "id" across the different levels of the factors.

Then, I simply run the command:

```
ezANOVA(data=ez_data, dv=.(choice), wid=.(id_r), within=.(cost,msg), between=.(rank), type=3)
```

But this still yields the error:

```
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data definitely has missing values. See output of `with(ez_data,table(id,cost,msg))`, or (following the suggestion in the error message) `ezDesign(data=ez_data,y=id,x=cost,col=msg)`

Ah, I see now that you likely posted merely a subset of your data. Still, as you note "Participants were randomly assigned to both `cost` and `msg` at two points in time, so theoretically they could have the same combination of `cost` and `msg` at both points in time.", this means that you could have missing data in the sense that some participants may not have data for all possible combinations of `msg` and `cost`, which is necessary if you want to treat those variables as manipulated within-Ss.

Comment: Thanks! I'd just stumbled to the conclusion that it may be more appropriate to use a mixed model (where subjects are treated as a random factor) for this very reason. For example, using `lmer` I'm playing with models such that: `m1 = lmer(choice ~ cost + msg + rank + (cost|id) + (msg|id), data=data)` if using lmer. Does this seem like a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

I solve my problem based on [this solution](https://github.com/mike-lawrence/ez/issues/29).

You can identify the missing data by

```
#Dataframe with your ANOVA wid (Subjects)
temp = as.data.frame(table(data$YourWid))

#Use the number of levels from you within variables
#Returns only the subjects that have less than number of levels (Missing data)
temp[temp$Freq<2,]
```