# ezANOVA produces "missing cells" error when no cellls are missing

Tags: r, anova

I am experiencing a problem with ez that is similar to the one described in this thread: 
[Error in `ezANOVA` with balanced dataset with no missing data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/error-in-ezanova-with-balanced-dataset-with-no-missing-data/394853#394853)

Specifically, I am getting the error message

```
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  :  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

while I am fairly confident my dataset actually does not contain any missing cells.

My dataframe looks something like this:

```
      id                     szenario measurement  default   PI  congruency    ego avoidability
694   170     Con_Inac_1_SAP_Orphanage           0 inaction high   congruent    ego    avoidable
10396 170   Con_Inac_4_SII_Cliffhanger           0 inaction  low   congruent    ego   inevitable
15247 170       Incon_Inac_6_OAI_Nobel           0 inaction  low incongruent no_ego    avoidable
19405 170  Incon_Inac_7_OII_Euthanasia           1 inaction  low incongruent no_ego   inevitable
26335 170         Incon_Ac_2_SAI_Ebola           1   action  low incongruent    ego    avoidable
27721 170        Incon_Ac_3_SIP_Rescue           1   action high incongruent    ego   inevitable
33958 170      Con_Ac_5_OAP_Transplant           0   action high   congruent no_ego    avoidable
40888 170             Con_Ac_8_OIP_Spy           0   action high   congruent no_ego   inevitable
4160  171       Incon_Inac_2_SAI_Ebola           1 inaction  low incongruent    ego    avoidable
8318  171      Incon_Inac_3_SII_Rescue           1 inaction  low incongruent    ego   inevitable
14555 171    Con_Inac_5_OAI_Transplant           0 inaction  low   congruent no_ego    avoidable
18713 171           Con_Inac_8_OIP_Spy           0 inaction high   congruent no_ego   inevitable
22871 171       Con_Ac_1_SAP_Orphanage           0   action high   congruent    ego    avoidable
29801 171     Con_Ac_4_SIP_Cliffhanger           1   action high   congruent    ego   inevitable
34652 171         Incon_Ac_6_OAP_Nobel           0   action high incongruent no_ego    avoidable
41582 171    Incon_Ac_7_OII_Euthanasia           1   action  low incongruent no_ego   inevitable
1389  175       Incon_Inac_2_SAP_Ebola           0 inaction high incongruent    ego    avoidable
5547  175      Incon_Inac_3_SIP_Rescue           0 inaction high incongruent    ego   inevitable
11784 175    Con_Inac_5_OAP_Transplant           0 inaction high   congruent no_ego    avoidable
21486 175           Con_Inac_8_OII_Spy           0 inaction  low   congruent no_ego   inevitable
25644 175       Con_Ac_1_SAI_Orphanage           0   action  low   congruent    ego    avoidable
32574 175     Con_Ac_4_SII_Cliffhanger           0   action  low   congruent    ego   inevitable
37425 175         Incon_Ac_6_OAI_Nobel           0   action  low incongruent no_ego    avoidable
38811 175    Incon_Ac_7_OIP_Euthanasia           0   action high incongruent no_ego   inevitable
4162  177       Incon_Inac_2_SAI_Ebola           1 inaction  low incongruent    ego    avoidable
8320  177      Incon_Inac_3_SII_Rescue           0 inaction  low incongruent    ego   inevitable
14557 177    Con_Inac_5_OAI_Transplant           0 inaction  low   congruent no_ego    avoidable
18715 177           Con_Inac_8_OIP_Spy           1 inaction high   congruent no_ego   inevitable
22873 177       Con_Ac_1_SAP_Orphanage           0   action high   congruent    ego    avoidable
29803 177     Con_Ac_4_SIP_Cliffhanger           0   action high   congruent    ego   inevitable
34654 177         Incon_Ac_6_OAP_Nobel           1   action high incongruent no_ego    avoidable
41584 177    Incon_Ac_7_OII_Euthanasia           1   action  low incongruent no_ego   inevitable`
```

When running ANOVAs, it works out for most of them, meaning none of the one factor ANOVAs produce an error, and almost none of the two-factor ANOVAs do. However, for the following two-factor ANOVA I get the error message described above:

```
default_PI_model <- ezANOVA(data = df6, dv = .(measurement), wid = .(id), within = .(default, PI), within_full = .(default,congruency,ego,PI,avoidability), detailed = TRUE, type = 3)
```

--->

```
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  :  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.
```

I see that the design for the default x PI interaction is less balanced than for the other factor combinations, but the two-level interaction should still be computable, I think.

Does anybody have an idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does this question differ from the one you cite at the outset?  It looks identical to me.  If it's not, could you please demonstrate that it is different?

Comment: The question is indeed the same, but when I posted in the other thread I was asked by a moderator to submit it as a new question, so that is what I did. So yes, I may have the same problem, but so far no solution for it. Maybe I'm also not getting the sense behind using 'temp = as.data.frame(table(df6id))′  as proposed there. But for me this just returns 1 for all participants and thus doesn't seem to diagnose anything.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding.  The moderator's intention was for you to post *anything that might be different, new, or in addition* to the existing question.  This protocol is perhaps the most basic element of every SE site: we aim not to have duplicate (and therefore variable and confusing) threads.